# Can't produce an executable jar from Spring Boot, Gradle, and IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot Microservice using IntelliJ-Idea and Gradle as the build engine. I have made no changes to the initial Spring Boot configuration. I also have made no modifications to the **build.gradle** file provided. I built the application using **starter.spring.io** through IntelliJ-Idea and have the following dependencies:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
```

The application currently contains 12 classes and 2 interfaces and is a Web Service provider. It runs fine on my system but when I build with Gradle, the Manifest.MF contains no **Main-Class** entry.

I created a very simple Hello World app and tried several combinations of IDE’s and build tools(Gradle and Maven)
and got the following results:

[image]

Interestingly, I was able to produce executable jars in Eclipse which has a separate Runnable JAR Export process.

I'm fairly new to IntelliJ and Gradle. Has anyone see this behavior before? Any ideas what I might be doing wrong in IntelliJ? I have my Hello World project zipped up if anyone needs it.

Comment: You should (well actually MUST) use gradle (or maven) to create the artifiact NOT the export function of your IDE. If you don't the specific Spring Boot plugins won't run and your jar won't be in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the advise of **M. Denium** and I did the Gradle build from the Command Line. The jars created were formatted correctly to be executable. Everything worked like a charm. In fact the Main-Class is a Spring Boot class called  **org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher** and the main class for my app was in a property called **Start-Class**. The IDE totally misses this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to include spring boot plugin for gradle - `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin`

More details in the [gradle section of the getting started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)